# Why can’t I see the database list in the DolphinDB web interface?

Tags: acl, dolphindb

I am using the DolphinDB web interface with the DB_READ privilege. However, I cannot access the databases in the web interface. I am wondering if it is because that I’m not granted the DB_MANAGE permission.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only an administrator or a user with the DB_MANAGE permission can access all databases on the current node.

To check your privileges, you can use the `getUserAccess` function.